# If I buy an iPhone app will I have to re-purchase the app if I get a new iPhone?

Tags: iphone, applications, ios-appstore

I upgraded from the 3G to the iPhone 4 and forgot to backup and transfer my apps. If I attempt to purchase apps that I have previously purchased, will the Apple store charge me? Or will it recognize that I have already purchased the app based on my apple ID?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, you will not be charged. You can re-download them in iTunes or directly on the phone. You'll have to hit the "buy" button, but after it starts downloading, you should see a message saying you already bought it once. The alert box includes a button to go ahead and re-download the app, which you will then not be charged for.

Comment: Just make sure you use the same iTunes account that you use(d) for the old phone! If you use a different account, then you will be charged again!

Answer (score 6):

according to the [caliban](https://superuser.com/users/9352/caliban) answer on [SU](https://superuser.com/questions/37591/what-iphone-apps-have-i-already-purchased):

To re-download all your apps into iTunes.

```
   1. First you need to authorize your iTunes. (Store > Authorize Computer)
   2. Next, check for available downloads (Store > Check For Available Downloads)
```

iTunes will then check for what you have purchased before, and give you an option to re-download your purchased apps.

To see a listing of all the apps you have purchased or downloaded, do this :

```
   1. Go to Store > View My Account
   2. Login
   3. Click on "Purchase History"
```

You should now see all the apps you have downloaded before