# Buying an app on two iDevices using the same account

Tags: ios-appstore

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [If I buy an iPhone app will I have to re-purchase the app if I get a new iPhone?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3125/if-i-buy-an-iphone-app-will-i-have-to-re-purchase-the-app-if-i-get-a-new-iphone)

This may be a duplicate of another question, but I was new to the site and I didn't check other questions. Feel free to close if this is a duplicate.

I'll proceed with my question.

1. Me and my brother both own an iPad, and we both wanted the same app on our respective iPads. So now if I buy an app on my iPad and give my account password to my brother, will Apple charge me again to buy the same app on my brother's iPad?

Comment: Never mind. I got the answer now.

Comment: Please post as an answer so that we can see that this question has been answered. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This question is an exact duplicate of [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3125/if-i-buy-an-iphone-app-will-i-have-to-re-purchase-the-app-if-i-get-a-new-iphone) question.